# Google Cloud Storage using django-appengine-toolkit

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently using django-appengine-toolkit project on my GAE project. I want to provide a feature in my app to upload pictures and store them in Google Cloud Storage buckets.

I've set up my APPENGINE_TOOLKIT setting like this:

```
APPENGINE_TOOLKIT = {
  (code over here)
  'BUCKET_NAME': '[my GCS bucket name]',
}

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'appengine_toolkit.storage.GoogleCloudStorage'
STATICFILE_STORAGE = 'appengine_toolkit.storage.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

What to to next? how this works with my models?

I read this tutorial http://dev.pippi.im/2014/02/10/create-a-blog-in-minutes-on-app-engine-with-django/

Thanks!

Comment: it transparently uses GCS to store files in from that point on. So where you have a "file" type model, it'll use GCS instead of "whatever".

Comment: Take a look here for a working example: https://github.com/masci/django_cloudstorage_example

Comment: Thanks Masci! I requested you an example for this a few weeks ago, sorry I forgot to reply back to you. Many thanks :)

Comment: It worked as Paul Collingwood said, but what about retrieving files url? Lets say I have pictures uploaded to my GCS folder and I want to show them in a template

Comment: @Masci : I too followed your blog post(http://dev.pippi.im/2014/02/10/create-a-blog-in-minutes-on-app-engine-with-django/) and later, saw your example that you mentioned above. I installed django-appengine-toolkit. But, when I try to run your example with suitable changes, it says,"No module named appengine_toolkit". Can you please tell me where can it be possibly wrong?